# Serverless Implementation of WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I do not know what I am doing wrong with implementing a serverless WebRTC.

1. Create Offer
2. Pass the offer to remote
3. Create an answer

I do not know what I am doing wrong with implementing a serverless WebRTC.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    var localStream, localPeerConnection, remotePeerConnection;
var servers = {"iceServers":[{"url":"stun:23.21.150.121"}]};

var sdpConstraints = {
        optional: [],
        mandatory: {
            OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
            OfferToReceiveVideo: true
        }
    };

var localVideo = document.getElementById("alice");
var remoteVideo = document.getElementById("bob");

var startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
var callButton = document.getElementById("callButton");
var hangupButton = document.getElementById("hangupButton");
var joinButton = document.getElementById("joinButton");

var localOffer = document.getElementById("localOffer");
var remoteOffer = document.getElementById("remoteOffer");
var localAnswer = document.getElementById("localAnswer");
var remoteAnswer = document.getElementById("remoteAnswer");

var showLocalOffer = document.getElementById("showLocalOffer");
var getRemoteOffer = document.getElementById("getRemoteOffer");
var showLocalAnswer = document.getElementById("showLocalAnswer");
var getRemoteAnswer = document.getElementById("getRemoteAnswer");

var sentLocalOfferButton = document.getElementById("sentLocalOfferButton");
var pasteRemoteOfferButton = document.getElementById("pasteRemoteOfferButton");
var sentLocalAnswerButton = document.getElementById("sentLocalAnswerButton");
var pasteRemoteAnswerButton = document.getElementById("pasteRemoteAnswerButton");

startButton.disabled = false;
callButton.disabled = true;
hangupButton.disabled = true;
joinButton.disabled = true;

showLocalOffer.style.display = 'none';
getRemoteOffer.style.display = 'none';
showLocalAnswer.style.display = 'none';
getRemoteAnswer.style.display = 'none';

startButton.onclick = start;
callButton.onclick = call;
joinButton.onclick = join;
hangupButton.onclick = hangup;
sentLocalOfferButton.onclick = showRemote;
pasteRemoteOfferButton.onclick = answerCreate;
pasteRemoteAnswerButton.onclick = answerRemote;
sentLocalAnswerButton.onclick = hideRemoteAnswer;

function trace(text) {
  console.log((performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) + ": " + text);
}

function start() {
  trace("Requesting local stream");
  startButton.disabled = true;
  getUserMedia({audio:true, video:true}, gotStream,
    function(error) {
      trace("getUserMedia error: ", error);
    });
}

function gotStream(stream){
  trace("Received local stream");
  localVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  localStream = stream;
  callButton.disabled = false;
  joinButton.disabled = false;
}

// ALICE

function call() {
    showLocalOffer.style.display = 'block';
    callButton.disabled = true;
    joinButton.disabled = true;
    hangupButton.disabled = false;
    trace("Starting call");

    if (localStream.getVideoTracks().length > 0) {
      trace('Using video device: ' + localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].label);
    }
    if (localStream.getAudioTracks().length > 0) {
      trace('Using audio device: ' + localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].label);
    }

    localPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    trace("Created local peer connection object localPeerConnection");

    localPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);
    trace("Added localStream to localPeerConnection");
    localPeerConnection.createOffer(gotLocalDescription,handleError,sdpConstraints);
}

function gotLocalDescription(description){
  localPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(description);
  trace("Offer from localPeerConnection SDP: \n" + description.sdp);
  trace("Offer from localPeerConnection TYPE: \n" + description.type);
  localOffer.value = JSON.stringify(description);
}

function showRemote() {
    showLocalOffer.style.display = 'none';
    getRemoteAnswer.style.display = 'block';
}

function answerRemote() {
  getRemoteAnswer.style.display = 'none';
    var remoteSesssionDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(remoteAnswer.value));
    localPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteSesssionDescription);
    localPeerConnection.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;
  localPeerConnection.onicecandidate = gotRemoteIceCandidate;
}

function gotRemoteIceCandidate(evt) {
    if (event.candidate) {
      localPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(evt.candidate));
      trace("Remote ICE candidate: \n " + evt.candidate.candidate);
    }
}


// BOB

function join() {
    trace("Joining call");
    getRemoteOffer.style.display = 'block';
    callButton.disabled = true;
    hangupButton.disabled = false;
    joinButton.disabled = true;

    remotePeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    trace("Created remote peer connection object remotePeerConnection");
}

function answerCreate() {
    getRemoteOffer.style.display = 'none';
    showLocalAnswer.style.display = 'block';

    var sessionDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(remoteOffer.value));
    remotePeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(sessionDescription);
    remotePeerConnection.createAnswer(gotRemoteDescription,handleError,sdpConstraints);
}

function gotRemoteDescription(answerSdp) {
    remotePeerConnection.setLocalDescription(answerSdp);
    trace("Answer from remotePeerConnection SDP: \n" + answerSdp.sdp);
    trace("Answer from remotePeerConnection TYPE: \n" + answerSdp.type);
    localAnswer.value = JSON.stringify(answerSdp);
    remotePeerConnection.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;
    remotePeerConnection.onicecandidate = gotLocalIceCandidate;

}

function hideRemoteAnswer() {
    showLocalAnswer.style.display = 'none';
}

function gotRemoteStream(evt) {
    console.log('evt: ', evt);
    remoteVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(evt.stream);
    trace("Received remote stream");
}

function gotLocalIceCandidate(evt){
  if (event.candidate) {
    remotePeerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(evt.candidate));
    trace("Local ICE candidate: \n" + evt.candidate.candidate);
  }
}

// GENERAL USE

function hangup() {
  trace("Ending call");
  localPeerConnection = null;
  remotePeerConnection = null;
  hangupButton.disabled = true;
  callButton.disabled = false;
  joinButton.disabled = false;

  showLocalOffer.style.display = 'none';
  getRemoteOffer.style.display = 'none';
  showLocalAnswer.style.display = 'none';
  getRemoteAnswer.style.display = 'none';
}

function handleError(){
    trace("Cannot Create Offer");
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong either. What is happening or not happening? How are you passing the offer and its answer?

Comment: I send the offer that was created to a friend that is remote and will use the offer to create the answer and also send the answer back @deceze

Comment: Like, how? Via chat? You'll also have to send a bunch of ICE candidates, not just SDP offers.

Comment: Yes, via chat @deceze.... How do you think I will be able to send the ICE candidates ?

Comment: You need to listen to `RTCPeerConnection.onicecandidate`. There can easily be upwards of 20-50 ICE candidates. I don't think it's very feasible to copy them over one by one.

Comment: Where do you think i will listen for RTCPeerConnection.onicecandiate.... @deceze

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onicecandidate

Comment: I think the problem is that RTCPeerConnection.onicecandidate is not being fire at all

Comment: I don't know about that, but you certainly got it hooked up wrong. `onicecandiate` you need to send that candidate to the remote peer, not to yourself.

Comment: Even though it's a dart library my code might help you: https://github.com/roberthartung/webrtc_utils/blob/master/lib/src/client/peer.dart#L95

Answer (score 1):

I've written one of these, which you can try in Firefox in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032884/why-signaling-server-needed-for-webrtc/29056385#29056385). Yes, typically with a server, you'd send ICE candidates over your signaling channel as soon as they become available.

But here that's impractical. I think you want ***one*** message to send to your friend. To do that, wait until the browser has had time to discover all ICE candidates. They will then be included in the offer/answer for you (Note: this may take up to 15 seconds on Windows in my experience).

One way to do this is to listen to `onnegotationneeded` until it returns a null candidate, signifying the end of ice gathering:

```
pc.onicecandidate = function(e) {
  if (e.candidate) return;
  var offerSdp = pc.localDescription.sdp;
  // send offerSdp string to friend
};
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `onnegotationneeded` event to check if a negotiation is needed. If that event is fired, you should create an offer and exchange it. You might want to check my code at [github](https://github.com/roberthartung/webrtc_utils/blob/master/lib/src/client/peer.dart#L95) that might help you.