# webrtc after signaling on LAN

Tags: webrtc, lan, signaling

After webrtc passes by a signaling server on Internet, how it works when two machines are running in the same network?

The data will be exchanged only on the network or will it still use internet ?

I am asking this because of our internet is not good, it's too slow. but our local network speed is very fast.. So I would like to know if the internet signal will affect the audio and video conversation.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the network configuration, the devices should connect directly over the local network. Please note that some browsers, such as Safari, may not share with the signalling service local ICE Candidates unless configured to do so (false concern over sharing network info). The devices must share local ICE Candidates, or else they will still stream via the external network or a TURN server, if available.