# Fetch net server from browser

Tags: node.js, fetch

Is it possible to fetch NodeJS Socket server from web browser ?

I've create `net` server and i would like request this server from web client :

```
const server = net.createServer();
server.listen(SERVER_PORT);
```

I've try to `fetch` with ip and port, but no result.

Anyone have idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. 
From web browser, you can only communicate through HTTP or WebSocket.
If you try to talk to a TCP server with the wrong protocol, it'll error out.

If you absolutly want your server to be a `net` TCP server, you can implement a server that communicate with your web app through a WebSocket and forward messages to your `net` server.

Otherwise, you could just do a `WebSocket` server, with [socket.io](https://socket.io/) for example.

Hope it helps,
regards

Comment: Hi boehm, thank for your response. I can only create `net TCP server`. Can i communicate with this server with socket.io client ?

Comment: If you're using node.js, I don't understand why you couldn't create a WebSocket server. if you're obligated to create a `net TCP server`, then you can create a socket.io server that communicate with your socket.io client (on your browser) and forward the client's messages to your `net TCP server`

Comment: I'm on react-native offline context. I can't use http module :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but what is your goal ?

Comment: I need to send message (webrtc offer) on offline connexion. So i need to create small server for this, and only TCP work.

Comment: What I understand is that you're trying to set up WebRTC connection on a local network (if not, why are you offline ?). I'm not sure I can help with that, it's way beyond the field of the question, but here's another [q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171367/webrtc-on-local-network) that might help you

Comment: Hi @s-leg3ndz if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.