# real time video streaming without webRTC peer setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I tried to build a video chat that would run through intranet. I used webkit *getUserMedia()* to capture user video and then draw it on a canvas as images . The imagedata is base64 encoded and sent to a nodejs server through websockets ( used socket.io ) using a 0 interval timeout. The images are reconstructed on the reciever side and drawn on a canvas to make it look like a video . Everything is working fine but the video is too slow .I tested it using a sony vaio with 6gb RAM .

This is a git repo for the code https://github.com/sourabh2k15/hackinout_webRTC

Solutions I am looking for implementation logic - lazy loading , clustering of pc's to improve server power .

Comment: I'm curious, why aren't you using WebRTC to do the video and audio? That's what it's build for, and it would very likely solve your speed problem. Should work great over intranet.

Comment: @jib  
because webRTC needs the internet atleast to setup the connection , so it cannot be used in an intranet without access to internet . The theme of the hackathon was to build something for rural india , so I made this .

Comment: You don't need the internet. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33559801/918910

Comment: @jib , thanks will try that , but I realized I have already written my own implementation ( although as slow as I lift my hand here and it goes in slow motion the other end of video ). But I am figuring out to apply some algo to make it faster !