# WebRTC video over p2p wireless link

Tags: angularjs, webrtc, p2p, wireless, video-conferencing

I would like to build a demonstrator for a wireless technology that connects two computers to each other. Without entering in the detail of the wireless technology, we could assume the network to be equivalent to having the two computers connected to each other through a very long Ethernet cable (miles long).

The demonstrator I have in mind is a permanent video conference link between the two computers. In practice what I would like to have is two monitors with webcams in the two remote locations which show real-time the video from the remote camera.

I thought that a good way to do it is to use WebRTC so that I can customise the look of the webpage, etc.

I read around a number of articles but I admit my knowledge is still all theoretical and I haven't written a line of code yet.

My questions are:

- Since the two IPs would be fixed without NAT, is it possible to have the video conference without any server so that the two computers can talk directly without any internet connection? Note that at least one computer might *not* have any internet connection if not through the other computer once the connection is established.
- If it is possible, are there implementations available? I found [Serverless-WebRTC](https://github.com/cjb/serverless-webrtc) but from what I understand only the signalling server is not used, but the STUN server still is.
- Is there an Angularjs available? I found [ng-simple-webrtc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-simple-webrtc) but I don't think it is serverless.

Finally - Maybe I am thinking to use the wrong tool for the job. If so, do you have better ones to suggest?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33559801/918910.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run WebRTC without access to the outside Internet. STUN is a mechanism to setup connections in the presence of NAT and firewalls, but if you have local network IP addresses that are reachable from each of your computers, you don't need STUN.

The Serverless-WebRTC forces the users to manually exchange the signaling that would take place on a server. This seems like a significant inconvenience. In your situation, you should just run the signaling server component on one of the two computers.

I doubt you will find a ready made signaling solution for your particular problem.

Comment: Thank you @mattm for the answer! So if I understood well what you suggest, I should not need STUNT but I would need to run the signalling server on one of the computers. Also, you suggest not to start my project from Serverless-WebRTC? Do you think ng-simple-webrtc would be a good place to start?

Comment: @user1472709 Sorry, I do not know anything about ng-simple-webrtc.

Comment: No problem. I reckon the best way to do it is to read more and get my hands dirty on the code. Thank you, and I'll update my question with more info if necessary!