# WebRTC remoteVideo stream not working

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have added a simple webRTC application where it will connect a browser window to itself, streaming video data from the my camera. The end goal is to get two video streams on the page, one coming from the camera directly and the other coming from a WebRTC connection that the browser has made locally.

Unfortunately the remote video stream is not showing up. Any idea why?

```
<video id="yours" autoplay></video>
<video id="theirs" autoplay></video>
```

And here's the javascript

```
function hasUserMedia() {
     navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.msGetUserMedia;

     return !!navigator.getUserMedia;
    }

    function hasRTCPeerConnection() {
     window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection 
        || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;

     return !!window.RTCPeerConnection;
    }

    var yourVideo = document.querySelector('#yours'),
     theirVideo = document.querySelector('#theirs'),
     yourConnection, theirConnection;


    if (hasUserMedia()) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false }, function(stream) {
         yourVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
         if (hasRTCPeerConnection()) {
            startPeerConnection(stream);
         } else {
         alert("Sorry, your browser does not support WebRTC.");
         }
         }, function (error) {
         console.log(error);
         });
        }else{
            alert("Sorry, your browser does not support WebRTC.");
        }


    function startPeerConnection(stream){
        var configuration = {
            "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302"
            }]
        };

        yourConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
        theirConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);



         // Setup stream listening
         yourConnection.addStream(stream);

         theirConnection.onaddstream = function (event) {
            theirVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
            console.log('stream added');
         };

         // console.log(yourConnection);
          //console.log(theirConnection);

         // Setup ice handling
         yourConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
         if (event.candidate) {
                 theirConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.
                candidate));
             }
         };
         theirConnection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
             if (event.candidate) {
                 yourConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.
                candidate));
             }
         };

          // Begin the offer
         yourConnection.createOffer(function (offer) {
            yourConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
            theirConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);

            theirConnection.createAnswer(function (offer) {
                theirConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
                yourConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
            });
         });
    };
```

I'm following Dan Ristic's book on WebRTC and understood what he did with the coding. Unfortunately, the remote video is not showing up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add ***failure callbacks*** to make it work. Not only won't you see errors otherwise, but doing so will actually make it work, for a really weird reason:

You're a victim of something called WebIDL overloading. 
What's happening is there are two versions of the WebRTC API, and you're mixing them.

There's a [modern promise API](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#interface-definition), e.g.:

```
pc.createOffer(options).then(successCallback, failureCallback);
```

and a [deprecated callback version](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#legacy-interface-extensions), e.g.:

```
pc.createOffer(successCallback, failureCallback, options);
```

In other words, there are two `createOffer` functions that take different number of arguments.

Unfortunately, you're hitting the first `createOffer` because you're only passing one argument! The first `createOffer` expects an [options](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-rtcofferoptions) object which unfortunately in WebIDL is indistinguishable from a function. It is therefore treated as a valid argument (an empty options object). Even if this had caused a `TypeError`, it wouldn't have caused an exception, because promise APIs reject the returned promise instead of throwing an exception:

```
pc.createOffer(3).catch(e => console.log("Here: "+ e.name)); // Here: TypeError
```

You're not checking the returned promise either, so errors are lost.

Here's a working version ([https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/gft3rc8c/) for Chrome):

```js
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection ||
                           window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

var yourConnection, theirConnection;

navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false }, function(stream) {
    yourVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

    var config = { "iceServers": [{ "urls": "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302"}] };
    yourConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
    theirConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);

    yourConnection.addStream(stream);

    theirConnection.onaddstream = function (event) {
        theirVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
    };

    yourConnection.onicecandidate = function (e) {
        if (e.candidate) {
            theirConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(e.candidate),
                                            success, failure);
         }
     };
     theirConnection.onicecandidate = function (e) {
         if (e.candidate) {
             yourConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(e.candidate),
                                            success, failure);
         }
     };

     yourConnection.createOffer(function (offer) {
         yourConnection.setLocalDescription(offer, success, failure);
         theirConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer, success, failure);
         theirConnection.createAnswer(function (offer) {
             theirConnection.setLocalDescription(offer, success, failure);
             yourConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer, success, failure);
         }, failure);
     }, failure);
}, failure);

function success() {};
function failure(e) { console.log(e); };
```

```html
<video id="yourVideo" width="160" height="120" autoplay></video>
<video id="theirVideo" width="160" height="120" autoplay></video>
```

But callbacks are laborious. I highly recommend the new promise API instead ([https](https://jsfiddle.net/aynr0k5q/) for Chrome):

```js
var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})
  .then(stream => pc1.addStream(video1.srcObject = stream))
  .catch(log);

var add = (pc, can) => pc.addIceCandidate(can).catch(log);
pc1.onicecandidate = e => add(pc2, e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => add(pc1, e.candidate);

pc2.ontrack = e => video2.srcObject = e.streams[0];
pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => log(pc1.iceConnectionState);
pc1.onnegotiationneeded = e =>
  pc1.createOffer().then(d => pc1.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
  .then(() => pc2.createAnswer()).then(d => pc2.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
  .catch(log);

var log = msg => console.log(msg);
```

```html
<video id="video1" height="120" width="160" autoplay muted></video>
<video id="video2" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video><br>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: woww. This answer made my day. I'm new to WebRTC and I'll disturb you very much in future!

Comment: I don't get it. I understand a lot but still not get it. This example should make connection with peer. So in second `video` I should see somebody else, not me, right?

Comment: @DamianHetman whom did you expect to see? :) This is a local-loop demo only. For a real call, you need to know whom to call first, and some signaling channel to exchange offer/answer across to set up the call.

Comment: @jib So how to do it with other caller? I'v searched examples on the web and almost every example was local-loop. I found one that allows to call other person but code was too old to work. I am trying to make make one to one video call but I don't know what am I doing wrong...

Comment: @DamianHetman That's because doing more requires a (websocket) server for signaling. See my other answers on [cross-tab demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39000919/918910), [cut'n'paste signaling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29056385/918910), and [local websocket server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33559801/918910). The second one you can use to connect to any machine anywhere (provided get the offer and answer back and forth manually).