# webRTC one to one audio call examples

Tags: webrtc, p2p

I am trying to make a one to one audio call using webRTC.
I have been looking through some of the source code on https://github.com/shanet/WebRTC-Example/blob/master/client/webrtc.js but I realized it has a middle man "iceServers" located at.

```
var peerConnectionConfig = {
    'iceServers': [
        {'urls': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'},
        {'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
    ]
};
```

I need my software to work when two peers are connected on the same network without internet connection. Could someone help me locate some examples or ideas if webRTC is possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I simplify WebRTC signalling for computers on the same private network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543346/can-i-simplify-webrtc-signalling-for-computers-on-the-same-private-network)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. Just set the ice servers to an empty array (remove the stun and the turn servers) and all should be fine on a local network.

Take care about Chrome HTTPS/WSS requirements (Chrome will not allow the media permission if your website is not on HTTPS which is a bit difficult to setup on a local LAN without any internet connection). Firefox and Edge doesn't have such requirements.

Comment: While Firefox does not make it compulsory to use HTTPS, it will not allow you to give permanent microphone permissions on an unsecured site.