# webRTC working example, multiple video chat

Tags: socket.io, webrtc, chat

after improving my PHP, CSS, JS, Skills I found years ago webWTC that had no support. Now in 2018 I see very nice things online with webRTC.

I love to learn more about it and found some nice "basic" examples.

**for some reason I can't figure out how I get video chat with multiple people. I donwload lots of examples but all of them give 404 errores.  missing Socket.io... or connection, missing css  files, javascript etc.**

Does one of you have a working script? I prefer not to use servers with special software installed. **I guess I'm to dumb for Socket.IO** even on the page "get started" with socket.io... i dont understand anything  of it.  I am using a directadmin server (shared). I cant install it.

lots of scripts online don't explain neither how to install it so I copied it to my server.. I guess I am missing something important. I've tried over 20 scripts.

Comment: We don't know what you don't understand. Also, you ask about multiple participants, yet sound like you're struggling with basic one-on-one calls? Please be more specific?

Comment: 1-one-one calls is very easy. its upload the code and it work. I can figure out how it work and change it like my needs.

Im new at webRTC and want to have a group of 4 cameras/users. I found lots of examples but none of them works when I upload it.  Its because of socket.io in my own opinion. I've tried to install it but don't understand it.

so 

--- if I can do it without socket.io... great!
-- if I really need socket.io.. I cant figure out how to get in on my webspace.

sorry.. I can do alot but never finished school :P and dont know tech-talk :P

Comment: Some form of signaling (e.g. WebSocket or socket.io) is needed even for one-on-one calls... Try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33559801/918910).

Comment: Sadly, seems nobody shared a simple PHP signaling server for many peers. [This Github project](https://github.com/bndr/webRTC-php) for 2 peers using just PHP, MySQL and XHR to do the signaling part, works well (with some updates in the code). Having seen that code working, I think a way to do a multiple peers version avoiding using Socket.io, Ratchet, etc. should be possible, although the code for signaling multiple peers is a bit more complex than the 2 peers version. However, seems the people who knows how to do what you want prefer to sell it.