# Webrtc on fails on local network without internet connectivity

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, stun, turn

Do I really need a stun/turn server on my local network to use Webrtc??

I have clone Google Webrtc codelab rep everything works fine as long as an connected to the internet.

Comment: You need at least a web service to exchange addresses.

Comment: Have you checked the webrtc repo?? I think it uses socket.io for that

Comment: I'm looking for evidence in the sample code of how it does it, but you still need a channel for endpoints for endpoints to rendezvous and exchange address candidates. That doesn't happen by accident.

Comment: Ok. Thanks alot

Comment: I think the node.js file is meant to be a sample rendezvous server.  ... https://github.com/googlecodelabs/webrtc-web/blob/master/step-06/index.js

Comment: Yes. But when am disconnected webrtc fails

Comment: Use Fiddler to debug...

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/33559801/918910