# Do we still need stun server and signalling server when one communicator has it's public IP

Tags: webrtc, remote-desktop

Our application like following. A will connect with B, so then B will sending video to A in real-time, and A will sending other information such as keyboard event to B, and B will always has it's own public IP. B will connect with only one user at the same time. It's actually just a remote desktop application with displaying and operated by browser.

I thought as A know B's IP, so A can just send the "offer" to a socket of B, and once B received an "offer", B will checked it and generate an "answer" as response to A. So then A can conncet with B. With B's ip was known, so A can connect with B, so B can send video to A directly?

I'm not sure if my idea is feasible? Is there anything wrong with my idea?

Thank you for you reading this problem. I will be very grateful if you can reply . This problem has been bothering me for days.

Comment: If you want WebRTC media over UDP, A would still need a STUN server to gather something other than host candidates to send to B I think to punch out through A's firewall, since WebRTC media cannot piggyback on the HTTP connection. You could of course [install a web socket server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33559801/918910) and a STUN server on B to solve this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I read more information about sdp protocol. Now It seems that I will always need stun server. Because even B has it's own internet Ip, but it can't know its internet Ip.So it still need stun server to tell it. Does it's true?