# Why does WebRTC needs ICE protocol to operate?

Tags: networking, protocols, webrtc, p2p

As far as I understand, ICE protocol is used for discovering the nodes/devices from the end-user device to "the outside".

I don't understand why it's needed. Isn't packet-routing is the responsibility of network devices like routers and switches? They should find the shortest path from the gateway to the end-user device (Actually, routers remembers those routes they previously discovered).

Moreover, NAT protocol is used to convert from an "internal ip" to "external ip" and vice-versa.

So again,
Why does the other user needs to be familiar with my internal network setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firewalls. They're typically configured to bounce any unsolicited traffic from the world wide web to you. They only approve of you initiating contact with a server, which only then is allowed to back-traffic to you, and that's pretty much it. Unless your friends all own static IPs (which few people can justify) this is a hostile environment for peer to peer communication.

ICE tries to solve this, by enumerating addresses and ports at which the other side may be reached, and trying to connect to these addresses, by initiating outbound requests on both ends, or if all else fails, falling back to communicating through a TURN server, if specified.

See this [WebRTCHacks article](https://webrtchacks.com/an-intro-to-webrtcs-natfirewall-problem/) for more on the problem.

> Why does the other user needs to be familiar with my internal network setup?

Because the other user is sometimes on your internal network. e.g. LAN games.

Answer (score 4):

NAT is a kludge, put in place to try to conserve IPv4 addresses until IPv6 becomes ubiquitous, and it breaks the end-to-end connectivity which is the promise of IP. Because of that, some things don't work correctly through NAT. There are various kludges to work around the NAT kludge, and ICE is part of that. This is explained in [RFC 5245, Interactive Connectivity Establishment (ICE): A Protocol for Network Address Translator (NAT) Traversal for Offer/Answer Protocols](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245):

> 1. Introduction
>
> [RFC 3264](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3264) [[RFC3264](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3264)] defines a two-phase exchange of Session Description
> Protocol (SDP) messages [[RFC4566](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566)] for the purposes of establishment of
> multimedia sessions.  This offer/answer mechanism is used by protocols
> such as the Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) [[RFC3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261)].
>
> Protocols using offer/answer are difficult to operate through Network
> Address Translators (NATs).  Because their purpose is to establish a
> flow of media packets, they tend to carry the IP addresses and ports
> of media sources and sinks within their messages, which is known to be
> problematic through NAT [[RFC3235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3235)].  The protocols also seek to create
> a media flow directly between participants, so that there is no
> application layer intermediary between them.  This is done to reduce
> media latency, decrease packet loss, and reduce the operational costs
> of deploying the application.  However, this is difficult to
> accomplish through NAT.  A full treatment of the reasons for this is
> beyond the scope of this specification.
>
> Numerous solutions have been defined for allowing these protocols to
> operate through NAT.  These include Application Layer Gateways (ALGs),
> the Middlebox Control Protocol [[RFC3303](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3303)], the original Simple
> Traversal of UDP Through NAT (STUN) [[RFC3489](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3489)] specification, and Realm
> Specific IP [[RFC3102](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3102)]  [[RFC3103](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3103)] along with session description
> extensions needed to make them work, such as the Session Description
> Protocol (SDP) [[RFC4566](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566)] attribute for the Real Time Control Protocol
> (RTCP) [[RFC3605](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3605)].  Unfortunately, these techniques all have pros and
> cons which, make each one optimal in some network topologies, but a
> poor choice in others.  The result is that administrators and
> implementors are making assumptions about the topologies of the
> networks in which their solutions will be deployed.  This introduces
> complexity and brittleness into the system.  What is needed is a
> single solution that is flexible enough to work well in all
> situations.
>
> This specification defines Interactive Connectivity Establishment
> (ICE) as a technique for NAT traversal for UDP-based media streams
> (though ICE can be extended to handle other transport protocols, such
> as TCP [[ICE-TCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245#ref-ICE-TCP)]) established by the offer/answer model.  ICE is an
> extension to the offer/answer model, and works by including a
> multiplicity of IP addresses and ports in SDP offers and answers,
> which are then tested for connectivity by peer-to-peer connectivity
> checks.  The IP addresses and ports included in the SDP and the
> connectivity checks are performed using the revised STUN specification
> [[RFC5389](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389)], now renamed to Session Traversal Utilities for NAT.  The
> new name and new specification reflect its new role as a tool that is
> used with other NAT traversal techniques (namely ICE) rather than a
> standalone NAT traversal solution, as the original STUN specification
> was.  ICE also makes use of Traversal Using Relays around NAT (TURN)
> [[RFC5766](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766)], an extension to STUN.  Because ICE exchanges a multiplicity
> of IP addresses and ports for each media stream, it also allows for
> address selection for multihomed and dual- stack hosts, and for this
> reason it deprecates [RFC 4091](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4091) [[RFC4091](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4091)] and [[RFC4092](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4092)].