# WebRTC - sharing one stream with multiple peers

Tags: webrtc

I have three peers:

- `PeerA` streams a local media to other peers
- `PeerB` accepts the stream and is located on the same machine as PeerA.
- `PeerC` accepts the stream and is located on a different machine.

All peers are Chrome latest.  The signalling server is functioning - I see all descriptions being sent and received as I'd expect.

The issue I'm encountering is that `PeerC`'s `onTrack` event is firing and I have access to the same `stream` (with the same `id`) that `PeerB` succesfully handles - but for some reason, the stream never appears in the DOM.

My code is based loosely on this: https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/js/main.js

What could be causing this?

Comment: Are you creating perrconnection & offer separately for Peer-B & Peer-C ?   Then check the setRemoteDescription is called with answer's from Peer-B & Peer-C are applied on appropriate peer connection?

Comment: @Ajay yes I am - and setLocal and SetRemote descriptions are both called from PeerC.  I'm totally willing to pay for an assist if you're open to some debugging; this has had me stumped for days.

Comment: Hi, @Ajay did you find a solution to this problem? I am stuck on the same issue but I am running it as an iOS app. The issue is that the same stream when shared with multiple peers, displays once in another device but the rest doesn't .

Comment: Is PeerC on a different network such as a cell network? It's also possible that you need to run this through a TURN server depending on the network PeerC is on. https://webrtcglossary.com/turn/