# An issue to share streams with multiple peers in WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc

Using latest Chrome. As far as I can tell, everything sets up correctly. Offer/Answer..Candidates..I expected...

However, one strange issue I noticed..and I googled...found that exactly same issue I am currently noticing...

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157738/webrtc-sharing-one-stream-with-multiple-peers
```

I also have three peers. What I want is that A sees B and C, B sees A and C, and C sees A and B.

Only one peer can see the other two peers, but the other two peers only see one...
BTW, I confirmed that each peer got notified onaddstream event two times, which is correct.

Here is what I did..

1. Once I get the stream, I stored this to my window.localStream...
2. Whenever a peer connection(since I support multiple peers, I managed this with dictionary) comes in, I added this localStream by peerConnection.addStream(window.localStream)
3. I set up the stream in video tag in peerConnection.onaddstream ...

Once the MediaStream is active and being transmitted then, this same stream cannot be transmitted to another peer at the same time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Sending the same stream to multiple peers should work. Compare your code to https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/ which shows how to achieve this. Your issue sounds like you might not set the answer on the right peerconnection. Inspecting eachs connection signalingState and iceConnectionState may provide further insight.

Comment: Each connection has correct offer/answer...iceConnectionState is connected, but the thing is that only peer that only sees one another peer has "checking" state, which is strange...I even checked LocalDescription/RemoteDescription...I didnt see any issue there...This particular peer didnt receive "Video" candidate..Obviously, I tried various options in CreateOffer, but no luck...only thing I can think of is ..somehow once the stream is being sent..then this stream is not being sent to another peer.....

Comment: @user10342556 Did you ever find an solution to this? Experiencing the exact same problem. Offer/Answer all sent and received correct but iceconnection state is stuck 'connecting' for the 3rd video which is blank

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, finally find out that It's because the sdp and ice candidate of the third client always be covered, only remain single peer of third client work.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a bit more about how you resolved this?