# Webrtc Call gets connected even if I'm not adding ice candidate in peer candidate

Tags: javascript, webrtc

```
const pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
const pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
async function call(){
    const offer = await pc1.createOffer();
    pc1.setLocalDescription(offer);
    pc2.setRemoteDescription(offer);
    const answer = await pc2.createAnswer();
    pc2.setLocalDescription(answer);
    pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription);
}
async function showVideo(){
    const config={audio:true,video:true};
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(config);
    pc1.addStream(stream);
}
```

This is simplified version of my code.

Now in this code I'm not adding icecandidate to the peer neither listening to onicecandidate. But if I invoke call() twice my connection gets established.

I used event handler for iceconnectionstate change and found that when I invoke call for first time it iceconnection state is in checking condition and when I invoke it for second time it gets called and state became completed.

So I'm wondering how does even without adding icecandidate to another peer how checking gets initiated and gets connected for the second time?

Comment: This title will probably not catch the attention of those who can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new here. Can you help me out figuring out a catch title?

Answer (score 5):

**Four reasons:** A bug in your code, a behavior of Chrome, no firewall, and something about how trickle ICE works.

#### 1) A bug in your code

First things first: The following sets `pc1.setRemoteDescription(null)`:

```
pc2.setLocalDescription(answer);
pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription); // pc2.localDescription == null here
```

...because `setLocalDescription` is an [asynchronous method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) that doesn't complete immediately.

Now `pc2.localDescription` does *eventually* get set, so the ***second*** time you invoke `call()` it's there, and negotiation works.

To fix this you must wait on the [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) using `await` or `then`:

```
await pc2.setLocalDescription(answer);
pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription); // pc2.localDescription is set!
```

#### 2) No ICE server needed if there's no NAT.

The browser can communicate with other machines on the same LAN, or itself, using "host" candidates (your machine's IP). No ICE servers needed to discover those.

#### 3) Trickle ICE is an optimization.

The signaling (trickling) of individual ice candidates using `onicecandidate`, is an optimization meant to speed up negotiation. Once `setLocalDescription` succeeds, the browser's internal *ICE Agent* starts, inserting ICE candidates, as they're discovered, into the `localDescription` itself. Wait a few seconds to negotiate, and trickling isn't necessary at all: all ICE candidates will be in the offer and answer transmitted.

#### 4) An interesting behavior in Chrome.

I suspect a race where the second time you invoke `call()` Chrome's ICE agent remembers the host candidates it has collected from last time, and inserts them into the offer and `localDescription` immediately, before `setLocalDescription`'s success callback has run to completion. This *might* be a bug, or it may be how the spec says it should work. In any case, the behavior seems to differ depending on browser atm, so I wouldn't rely on it today.

#### Steps to Reproduce / Proof of ICE in SDP

1. Run [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/zv9mL62p/) in Chrome and Firefox.
2. Click The `Call!` button once, then once more.
3. Observe Firefox: you'll see `0 candidates` (output twice); both times; no connection.
4. *Observe Chrome: it connects with `3 candidates` the* ***second*** *time, with candidates.*
5. Now uncomment the line `//  await wait(2000);`
6. *Both* browsers now connect, with `4` or `8 candidates` after 2 seconds.

The actual number of candidates may vary on your system, but the behavior shouldn't.

When I run this in Firefox, It doesn't connect either time, unless I modify it to wait or trickle candidates).

***Browser update:*** *Both browsers have bugs: Firefox is [too restrictive](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1509979) and Chrome is [too lenient](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=10001) in recovering from ICE failure.*

Comment: I've a doubt with your 3rd point. "Agent starts, inserting ICE candidates, as they're discovered, into the localDescription itself." Digging deeper into the RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent object contains sdp information; but the SDP doesn't not contains icecandidate. But you are telling that sdp contains information about ice-candidate. So can you share any resources where it was mentioned or any ways to check it locally?

Comment: I've added a fiddle that should show it above. You can also check out [an older answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032884/why-signaling-server-needed-for-webrtc/29056385#29056385).

Comment: There's some question of which browser is correct. I'll come back and update once that's resolved! In any case, I hope the information is helpful.