# Android WebRtc play dialing sound for outgoing calls

Tags: android, audio, webrtc, android-mediaplayer, playback

I'm working on a project that involves WebRtc for Android and everything is working fine accept for the fact that I don't know how I can play the standard repeating beep sound when you are waiting for that the person you are calling accepts your call. 
I have searched a lot for this but accept for a link that was related to IOS which wasn't very helpful, there was nothing useful.
Does anybody know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Just play it locally? This has nothing to do with WebRTC.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. If you can tell me if there is an API to play this kind of sound or how I can generate  these sounds, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Find it on the internet, and then play it?

Comment: As I mentioned before, I have already searched for it but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there's is no special "API to play this kind of sound". It's just like playing any other sound. Asking how to find an "outgoing" `rings.wav` on the internet, is out of scope for stackoverflow.

If you're looking to generate it, you'd need to specify which sound you want, since there is no "standard" one. The sound varies from market to market. Traditionally even, on old POTS networks, the sound was literally sent from the other side, producing different sounds when calling people in other countries.

Also, "ringing" is an app choice, and [out of scope for WebRTC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29056385/918910). Most WebRTC apps these days tend to pair people up using "rooms" or similar abstractions, rather than the traditional "pick up!" model.