# Serverless WebRTC SDP / ICE Timeout

Tags: firefox, webrtc, sdp, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

I am creating a serverless webRTC connection therefore I manually relay SDP info between two machines. If the response SDP is not given within a very short period of time after the offer SDP, the connection fails/times out. Is there a way to extend the amount of time between offering an SDP and ICE/RTC timeout? Is there another solution or workaround for this? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "very short"? I have no trouble [cut'n'pasting offers and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29056385/918910) between machines, even if it takes several seconds.

Comment: I waited 2 minutes before pasting the answer and it still worked.

Comment: Check out this demo. https://owebio.github.io/serverless-webrtc-chat/ . In FF, status changes to 'failed' after clicking the Create button and waiting 10-15 seconds. Does not happen in Chrome apparently.

Comment: Upgrade to Firefox 65 (out in 2 weeks). The 15 second ICE timeout appears to have been fixed there. Your demo wfm there even after waiting 20 minutes.

Comment: Thanks jib! Solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with Firefox 118.0.2, when trying to establish a webRTC connection between different browser tabs on the same machine.

The timeout is 5 seconds.

I found if I disable mDNS obfuscation, by setting media.peerconnection.ice.obfuscate_host_addresses in about:config to False, that the connection will work every time (no 5 second timeout).

Also, when exchanging SDPs, if I substitute the obfuscated Ip address in the SDP (eg, 44e489d0-7119-4c7a-9701-cc1ce50329ea.local) for the machine's local IP (eg, 192.168.10.4), the connection will work every time (no timeout issue either).

This would lead me to believe there is an issue with mDNS. Chrome does not appear to have this issue, so that would pinpoint the issue to Firefox.

Both workarounds that aren't going to work for production code deployed to end users.... Not sure how to work around this, as I can't deploy to production with this issue in place...

Comment: I believe the problem is detailed in this bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1647289 - here is the response from mozilla: "We have this timeout to allow better detection of ICE failures; the copy/paste/email use-case is not as important to us. If you want, you can change the media.peerconnection.ice.trickle_grace_period pref to something longer."

Answer (score -1):

More details from comments:

> Check out this demo. [owebio.github.io/serverless-webrtc-chat](https://owebio.github.io/serverless-webrtc-chat/). In FF, status changes to 'failed' after clicking the Create button and waiting 10-15 seconds. Does not happen in Chrome apparently.

Upgrade to Firefox 65 (out in 2 weeks). The 15 second ICE timeout appears to have been fixed there. Your demo wfm there even after waiting 20 minutes.