# WebRTC connection gets established, only if the created answer is accepted in less than 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p, peer

Hey I'm building an app that demonstrates the capabilities of webrtc. This app involves manual exchange of offer/answer. The issue I'm running into is, if the created answer is not accepted within 10 seconds in firefox browser, (15 seconds - chrome) the iceConnectionState property returns 'failed'. However if the answer is accepted within 10 seconds, then the connection is established and iceConnectionState returns 'connected'. Can somebody look at my code, and tell me what could be causing this behavior? Is there a bug in my code?

```
export default class P2P {
  constructor() {
    this.peerConnection;
    this.dataChannel;
    this.configuration = {
      iceServers: [
        {
          urls: ['stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302']
        }
      ],
      iceCandidatePoolSize: 100
    };
  };

  createPeerConnection = async () => {
    this.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(this.configuration);
    this.openDataChannel();

    this.peerConnection.addEventListener('connectionstatechange', (e) => {
      console.log(this.peerConnection.connectionState)
    });
  };

  openDataChannel = () => {
    let options = { 
      reliable: true 
   }; 
    
    this.dataChannel = this.peerConnection.createDataChannel('test', options);
    this.dataChannel.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
  };

  getIceCandidates = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.peerConnection.onicegatheringstatechange  = () => {
        if (this.peerConnection.iceGatheringState === "complete") {
          console.log('ice gathering complete')
          resolve();    
        };
      };

      this.peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
        console.log(this.peerConnection.iceConnectionState,     this.peerConnection.iceGatheringState);
      };
    });
  };

  createOffer = async () => {
    this.createPeerConnection();
    let offer = await this.peerConnection.createOffer();
    console.log("created-offer");
    offer = new RTCSessionDescription(offer);
    await this.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    await this.getIceCandidates();
    return JSON.stringify(this.peerConnection.localDescription);
  };

  acceptOffer = async (offer) => {
    this.createPeerConnection();
    offer = new RTCSessionDescription(offer)
    await this.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
  };

  createAnswer = async () => {
    let answer = await this.peerConnection.createAnswer();
    console.log("created-answer");
    answer = new RTCSessionDescription(answer);
    await this.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
    await this.getIceCandidates();
    return JSON.stringify(this.peerConnection.localDescription);
  };

  acceptAnswer = async (answer) => {
    if (!this.peerConnection.currentRemoteDescription) {
      this.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(answer);
      console.log('accepted')
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54167645/serverless-webrtc-sdp-ice-timeout

Comment: Can you press F12 to check what error message is shown in the console?

Comment: @TheKNVB WebRTC: ICE failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more details

Comment: Adding a TURN server may make your code work, I have signed up for a free TURN server from expressturn.com. And I have created a web page that is similar to yours. Unfortunately, in the Firefox browser, it works intermittently. However, it is working properly in the Chrome browser.

Can you post your peerConnection.onicecandidate event handler?

Comment: I used two arrays to store all ice for each party, For each party, I will add the ICE after setting the remote description.

Comment: @TheKNVB I am using 'onicegatheringstatechange' instead of 'onicecandidate', to detect the completion of gathering ice candidates. You can see it in the getIceCandidates method.

Comment: however, you have to add the remote ICE candidates to the local peerConnection object, I cannot find it in your code.

Comment: @TheKNVB the ICE candidates are already included in the local description, because If you notice I wait until the local ice candidates have been gathered before getting the local description. This all inclusive local description just needs to be shared and accepted by both the peers to establish the connection.

Comment: As I know it is wrong, you may refer to the following web page:
https://webrtc.org/getting-started/peer-connections#ice_candidates

Comment: It is another example:
https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#simple-peer-to-peer-example

Comment: @TheKNVB its not really wrong per-say. Its just how you need to do it, for a completely server-less implementation. In the examples, you shared, signalling happens through a websocket server. My site doesn't rely one. Look at this example https://svarunan.github.io/serverless-webrtc/ if you notice, the offer and the answer already include the ice candidates, my site is similar to this.

Answer (score -1):

Manual exchange of offer/answer is not really a supported use-case.
WebRTC uses ICE (which stands for *Interactive* Connectivity Establishment) for NAT traversal and this consumes resources every second.

A ICE candidate pool size of 100 is a complete waste of resources btw.

Answer (score -1):

Have you used the "perfect negotiation" logic when establishing a connection?

You may refer to the following page for detail:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation