# Android (Kotlin) WebRTC - "Failed to parse: "". Reason: Invalid SDP line"

Tags: kotlin, webrtc-android

I'm working on integration of WebRTC into a project and using "implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.30039'". When I just use the example project from Google source https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/, it works fine without any issue. However when converted all the Java files to Kotlin and run, it always throw the below error (Invalid SDP line). I did verify that the SDP is similar between Java and Kotlin project. Also I tried adding new line at the end of SDP as recommended in some forum, didn't help either.

Below is the error that I see in the Logcat when tried creating offer:

```
E/webrtc_sdp.cc: (line 402): Failed to parse: "". Reason: Invalid SDP line.
E/PCRTCClient: Peerconnection error: setSDP error: SessionDescription is NULL.
```

Following is the SDP:

```
    v=0
    o=- 3703865506153758141 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    s=-
    t=0 0
    a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
    a=msid-semantic: WMS ARDAMS
    m=video 9 RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127 124 125
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:WMCz
    a=ice-pwd:7U8pMIKV8KizMp6zeYgpnD6X
    a=ice-options:trickle renomination
    a=mid:0
    a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
    a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
    a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
    a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
    a=extmap:12 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
    a=extmap:11 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
    a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
    a=extmap:8 http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07
    a=extmap:9 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
    a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
    a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
    a=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
    a=sendrecv
    a=msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtcp-rsize
    a=crypto:0 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:xpIiJ7ZL8lDPOZbcBrMV8Q0kH/7K2bwborNljNEq
    a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
    a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
    a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:97 apt=96
    a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
    a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
    a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:99 apt=98
    a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
    a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
    a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
    a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:101 apt=100
    a=rtpmap:127 red/90000
    a=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:124 apt=127
    a=rtpmap:125 ulpfec/90000
    a=ssrc-group:FID 3892029952 1800496854
    a=ssrc:3892029952 cname:1P/brKdD8UOBMgTV
    a=ssrc:3892029952 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0
    a=ssrc:3892029952 mslabel:ARDAMS
    a=ssrc:3892029952 label:ARDAMSv0
    a=ssrc:1800496854 cname:1P/brKdD8UOBMgTV
    a=ssrc:1800496854 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0
    a=ssrc:1800496854 mslabel:ARDAMS
    a=ssrc:1800496854 label:ARDAMSv0
    m=audio 9 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:WMCz
    a=ice-pwd:7U8pMIKV8KizMp6zeYgpnD6X
    a=ice-options:trickle renomination
    a=mid:1
    a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
    a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
    a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
    a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
    a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
    a=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
    a=sendrecv
    a=msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSa0
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=crypto:0 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:xpIiJ7ZL8lDPOZbcBrMV8Q0kH/7K2bwborNljNEq
    a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
    a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
    a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
    a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
    a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
    a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
    a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
    a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
    a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
    a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
    a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
    a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
    a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
    a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
    a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
    a=ssrc:167068800 cname:1P/brKdD8UOBMgTV
    a=ssrc:167068800 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSa0
    a=ssrc:167068800 mslabel:ARDAMS
    a=ssrc:167068800 label:ARDAMSa0
```

Anyone seen similar issue when using WebRTC lib in Kotlin based android app ?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue. The problem is, according to [this discuss-webrtc](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/CEG0odmqlCo) mailing list thread, `\r\n` is required at the end of the session description.
You can fix this by simply appending `\r\n` at the end of the description string when constructing your `SessionDescription` object, eg.:

```
val sdp = SessionDescription(origSdp.type, "${sdpDescription.trim()}\r\n")
```

There is also a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=414395&thanks=414395&ts=1410809385) tracking this cryptic error message.

Comment: For my situation (I migrated my apps to Kotlin), only newline character "\n" is needed. Reminder to ensure both local and remote SDP SessionDescription are modified.

Comment: In my situation was 2 new lines at the end, i think requires only 1 new line